# Gender of loanwords from English ending in -ing

Tags: anglais, genre, emprunts, suffixes

The loanwords bowling, casting, rafting, shopping and zapping are masculine. Is it true that loanwards from English ending in -ing are generally masculine? If so, are there any exceptions?

EDIT: My intent was to only ask about loanwards from English that are gerunds (verbal nouns) ending in  -ing. Sorry for the inaccurate omission. (Still, the comments below mentioning the words "string" and "starking" are helpful.)

Comment: By default, an english word is masculine in french. But for instance, "un bowling" isn't used often, saying "du bowling" or "une partie de bowling" is more common, and doesn't take care of masculine/feminine...

Comment: [This site](http://www.listesdemots.com/motsfinissantparing.htm) claims to list all french words that end with `-ing` (note that some of those aren't English loanwords, and a lot of those I wouldn't really consider as 'french'). I haven't checked everything, but the only english loanword I can think of ending in -ing that's feminine is *une string*, which is a string in computer science (*un string* also exists and is a *thong*, so don't mix up the two ...)

Comment: There is also "Une starking" (apple) like we say "Une golden".

Comment: @Random I'd appreciate it if you could point me to a reference substantiating that (at least most recently borrowed) Englsh words are by default masculine in French? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted that as a comment because I have no source confirming it. Don't you find something on Google about it ? Otherwise let's wait for a real answer :)

Comment: Sure, I'm actually searching for a credible source right now (not, say, a seemingly random blog). A notable exception seems to be "la star"? Thanks!

Comment: @Fatalize A string in the computer sense is “une chaîne de caractères”, or “une chaîne” for short. “Une string” is uncommon franglais, with the feminine article coming from the proper term “chaîne” that the speaker has in mind.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the observation. Perhaps the same applies to jlliagre's comment regarding the feminine gender of starking (since it is "la pomme").

Comment: @Gilles True, but I wouldn't say "string" is uncommon in a computer science context. If anything, it is significantly more used than "chaîne de caractères".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Le nombre des emprunts en *-ing* est en progression constante.[...] Il
>   reste que les emprunts en *-ing* n'ont souvent qu'une existence éphémère
>   et ne pénètrent pas réellement la langue.[...] Le fait est révélateur
>   de la pression exercée sur le lexique français.
>
> [Trésor de la langue française informatisé, *TLFi*, [*-ing*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ing), section
>   *productivité* ]

Généralement on peut remarquer que la marque du pluriel n'affecte pas la prononciation qui demeure comme au singulier (par ex. le substantif *smoking(s)*, [smɔkiŋ]), et que les emprunts liés à des activités sont rares avant le 20<sup>e</sup>. On a certaines indications supplémentaires sur le genre de certains emprunts dans un corpus comme [*OpenLexique*](http://www.lexique.org/moteur/complexe.php?regex=1&nom_champs%5B1%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B1%5D=&champs%5B1%5D=.*ing%24&nom_champs%5B2%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B2%5D=&champs%5B2%5D=&nom_champs%5B3%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B3%5D=&champs%5B3%5D=&nom_champs%5B4%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B4%5D=&champs%5B4%5D=&tri=RAND%28%29&sens=ASC&pers%5B0%5D=*&pers%5B0%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B1%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B2%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B3%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B4%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B5%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&database=lexique.lexique3&lienbdd=&Rechercher=Rechercher&nblignes=500&format=html).

---

Au *LBU* (§164 ; voir ci-dessous), on note que le suffixe -ing ne semble pas s'appliquer à des radicaux français. Par ailleurs on discute aussi des hésitations avec *[holding](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/holding)*, réduction de *holding company*, et donc de l'idée sous-jacente de la *société*, nom féminin.

> **Remarque**. Conformément à la tendance générale pour les emprunts
>   désignant un inanimé, le mot est au masculin. Cependant, sous
>   l'influence de la lexie *société holding*, on trouve parfois le
>   féminin. [par ex. [*Ac.9*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/holding)].
>
> [*Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, *TLFi*, *holding* ]
>
> ---
>
> [...exemples de holding au féminin] — Mais le masculin prévaut selon
>   la plupart des dictionnaires, comme dans les autres noms en *-ing*.
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goose, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>, au §478a)1 ]

Le LBU donne l*eggin(g)* comme un exemple où on a des hésitations vu *jambière*, *guêtre*, deux parasynonymes féminins ; comme avec le/la *holding*. L'auteur *Nymansson* est parfois cité (par ex.  [« Le genre grammatical des anglicismes en français contemporain »](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&id=tudYAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22le%20genre%20grammatical%20des%20anglicismes%20contemporains%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=anglicisme), ds. *Cahiers de lexicographie*, 1995, et  [« Analyse grammaticale des formes en -ing »](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&id=MCVKAAAAYAAJ&dq=%C2%AB%20Le%20genre%20grammatical%20des%20anglicismes%20contemporains%20en%20fran%C3%A7ais%20%C2%BB&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=ing), ds. *Cahiers de lexicographie*, 1996). Enfin on mentionne un intérêt particulier pour les mots qui sont des gérondifs en anglais et donc on s'intéresse davantage à l'[anglicisme intégral](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=int%C3%A9gral&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) au départ. Les emprunts ne sont pas tous égaux, [en effet](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16717), et il y a une dynamique à l'emprunt.

Answer (score 1):

Every loanwards finishing by -ing are masculine but "holding" can be both masculine and feminine.

[source (french)](http://www.barbarisme.com/suffixe_ing.htm)